# Create multiple text files and add data from other file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have an original text file with blocks of data that I need to copy to another file and each block needs to be in an new file.

This is the block of data

```
HOST 123...

TEST ...

IP...

DONE...

HOST 123...

TEST ...

IP...

DONE...
```

After reading the original text file, will like to copy the block between `HOST` and `DONE` and paste to a new file and each time the block is found, paste the data to a different file.

At the end, it should be multiple files with the block of data on it.

So far I have the following:

```
$flag = 0 Get-Content file.txt
Get-Content
for each {Switch -Wildcard($_)
{"HOST" {$flag = 1} "DONE" {$flag = 0}}
if ($flag -eq 1){Out-File out.txt -InputObjects $_ -Append}}
```

Comment: Your script doesn't work at all and already fails on the first line. Fix your formatting for it so people might get an idea of what you actually got. It does seem to be headed in the right direction but has some logical issues.

Comment: please add a DIRECT example of the output desired. [*grin*] right now, i am unsure if you want `host` thru `done` _inclusive_ or _exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a better way to do this, but this should work for extracting the blocks excluding `HOST` and `DONE` lines:

```
$FileContents = Get-Content file.txt
$HostLines = ($FileContents | Select-String -Pattern "^HOST.*$" -AllMatches -CaseSensitive).linenumber
$DoneLines = ($FileContents | Select-String -Pattern "^DONE.*$" -AllMatches -CaseSensitive).linenumber

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $HostLines.count; $i++) {
    $FileContents[($HostLines[$i])..($DoneLines[$i]-2)] | out-file -FilePath ("File" + $i + ".txt")
}
```

The code above will extract your blocks into files starting with `File0.txt`, `File1.txt`, etc. Obviously, there could be cases where this doesn't work like if you have other lines that begin with `HOST` or `DONE` that you meant to include.

To include `HOST` and `DONE` lines:

```
$FileContents = Get-Content file.txt
$HostLines = ($FileContents | Select-String -Pattern "^HOST.*$" -AllMatches -CaseSensitive).linenumber
$DoneLines = ($FileContents | Select-String -Pattern "^DONE.*$" -AllMatches -CaseSensitive).linenumber

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $HostLines.count; $i++) {
    $FileContents[($HostLines[$i]-1)..($DoneLines[$i]-1)] | out-file -FilePath ("File" + $i + ".txt")
}
```

The loop works based on the accuracy of the `$HostLines` and `$DoneLines` contents. Both variable assignments are results of showing the line numbers after searching the text file. `$HostLines` contains an array of each line number that starts with `HOST`. `$DoneLines` contains an array of each line number that starts with `DONE`. The for loop uses `$i` to increment through each element of the arrays. `$HostLines[$i]` returns the value at array index `$i`. That value is a line number. `$HostLines[$i]-1` subtracts one from the line number because `$FileContents` is also an array. Array indexes start at 0 rather than 1. So if you want line number 3, you need `$FileContents[2]`. The `[1..4]` index contains a range operator `(..)`. This will return all values at indexes 1,2,3, and 4.

Here is an example of accessing array values:

```
$HostLines
1
9
$HostLines[0]
1
$HostLines[0]-1
0
$HostLines[1]
9
$HostLines[1]-1
8
```

Comment: Really appreciate your comment. Actually need the word HOST and DONE to be included. I believe should have mentioned that in the beginning, my apologies.

Comment: I added a second snippet to include those lines.

Comment: The script actually works!! Thank you very much. As a learning experience, do you mind explain the for loop? It is adding a count for the HostLines and then going through block?

Comment: I added more information. Let me know if that is sufficient.